# Priority Queue using doubly linked list

Tags: java, priority-queue, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a Priority Queue with a doubly linked list, but im stuck on the insertion of the nodes.

The task is:
A method to insert a new element to the list. To insert the element you should calculate the average of the first and last element in the list (if the list contains elements). If the new elements priority has a numerical value less than this average the element should be inserted from the beginning of the list, otherwise from the end of the list to save time.

```
    public class Node<Item> { //node class with priority, value and pointers to next and prev
    Item item;
    int  priority;
    Node next;
    Node prev;
}

public <Item> void add(Item value, int priority){ //fixa asap
    Node tmp = new Node();
    int currentpriority = sentinel.next.priority + sentinel.prev.priority / 2;

    if (sentinel.next == this.sentinel ) {  //if its empty add after sentinel
        sentinel.next.prev = tmp;
        tmp.next = null;
        tmp.prev = sentinel;
        sentinel.next = tmp;
        tmp.item = value;
        tmp.priority = priority;
    }

        else if (priority <= sentinel.next.priority){  //if the first element is larger than the new element replace it with the new one at the front
        sentinel.next.prev = tmp;
        tmp.next = sentinel.next;
        tmp.prev = sentinel;
        sentinel.next = tmp;
        tmp.item = value;
        tmp.priority = priority;
    }
    else if (priority >= sentinel.prev.priority){  //if the last element is smaller than the new element replace it with the new one at the front
        sentinel.prev.next = tmp;
        tmp.prev = sentinel.prev;
        tmp.next = null;
        sentinel.prev = tmp;
        tmp.item = value;
        tmp.priority = priority;
    }

        else if(priority <= currentpriority ) { // if true add FROM the front
            Node start = sentinel.next;
            while (priority > start.priority)
            start = start.next;
             System.out.println("Test from the front");
            tmp.next = start;
            tmp.prev = start.prev;
            start.prev = tmp;
            tmp.item = value;
            tmp.priority = priority;

    }
```

If I run this and insert 2 nodes i.e 1 with priority 1 and 3 with priority 3 I get
1 3

now I wish to insert 2 with priority 2
but it doesnt show up in the list, its still
1 3

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I assume the add() method is in the actual LinkedListObject Class, not in the Node Class. Also two questions: A) What is the sentinel reference? B) dont you keep track of head and tail, to actually get references of the first and last node, as your tasked needs it?

Comment: The sentinel is the head&tail reference it serves as both